# Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()

Tags: php, macos, postgresql, php-pgsql

Today I have updated my MacBook to OS X 10.12

After the update new configs (`httpd.config` and `php.ini`) were added and the old configs was renamed previous. I changed the confignames and everything works finde. Everything? No, postgres was not loaded. I created a `phpinfo()` `test.php` to check this. And yes, postgres was not loaded.

A view into the apache error log say:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function pg_connect().

Comment: You need to `pecl install pgsql`

Answer (score 0):

You have to install it. You can install it as below Ubuntu Terminal sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql

Mac OS Follow this link and let me know https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/

After everything is done, You can test by placing this in your index.php file